# LXDE and Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, lxde

I have LXDE desktop installed on Ubuntu 14.04 and Im having issues with the pcmanfmm file manager. Like if I try and copy a file from desktop to my secondary storage drive it says permission denied. I suspect this has to do with pcman. Ive been trying to find a way to get nautilus to work with LXDE but was unsuccesfull.

Anyone got any tips on how to get it working or why Im getting a permission denied when trying to copy files?

Comment: This sounds like a permission problem and should have nothing to do with the filemanager.

Comment: Well how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l ~/Desktop`? ([edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/502863/edit) it into your question)

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 718873 Jul 26 02:50 ftop.ru_43761.jpg

Comment: Do you have write permissions to your other drive? Try `ls -al /media/XXXXX` (replace XXXXX with the mount path of your drive)

Comment: Yeah thats what I figured that my other drive has no write permissions. How do I know what the mount path of the drive is? I know its sdb, but thats just the identification right?

Comment: I dont see my other drive in the media folder, all I see is my username folder,root and my windows partitions. The other drive is a 1TB storage drive as secondary drive divided into 4 partitions and they certainly show up in pcmanfm filemanager on left hand side where I can mount or unmount them but I cant write to them. Hmm, I can see them in my username folder if I mount them. Any idea whats going on and how could I get them to have write permissions?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out after a bit of research. I entered these commands in terminal for each sdb partition: sudo chown -R username:username /media/sdb1,   now I have write persmissions on the drive. Thanks for your help.